# Using LESS variables as CSS properties

Tags: css, variables, less, mixins

I have a mixin that converts px to em:

```
.margin(@target: @targetsize, @basefont: @em){
    margin:(@target / @basefont) + 0em;}
```

I'd like to change that mixin so that the CSS margin property is replaced with a variable. For example:

```
.pxtoem(@target: @targetsize, @basefont: @em, @property: @property){
@property:(@target / @basefont) + 0em;
```

}

So I could call it with, for example:

```
.pxtoem(2,1,margin-bottom);
```

Is this possible, and if so how?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the time, but there's an [open issue](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/36).

Comment: Dang. Oh well. Thanks for the link for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the less docs:

Parametric mixins can also have default values for their parameters:

```
.border-radius (@radius: 5px) {
  border-radius: @radius;
  -moz-border-radius: @radius;
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm after. In your example, you're using the @radius variable as a value to feed to the CSS property. I want the property (in your example it would be border-radius, -moz-border-radius, or -webkit-border-radius) to be replaced, not the value (in your example, 5px).

Answer (score 0):

Spotted this in searching for something related and noticed it hadn't been updated.

As of Less 1.6.0 [variable interpolation is now supported for properties](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties).

```
.setProp(@prop,@val) {
  @{prop}:@val
}

.foo {
  .setProp(opacity,0.75);
}
```